# Reading parameter from the request in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to read a parameter from the HttpServletRequest and check to see if it matches certain conditions. So the three conditions are

1. The value of the parameter can contain only alphanumerics (ASCII characters only), underscores, and dashes
2. It cannot begin with the dash.
3. It can be up to 200 characters long.

So I have written the following code to check if it matches the above conditions.

```
String tempParameter = request.getParameter("X");
if (tempParameter.matches("^[\\u0000-\\u007F]*$") 
    && tempParameter.length() <= 200        
    && !(tempParameter.substring(0, 1)).equals("-")) {
      A = tempParameter;
    }
```

So I run the servlet and pass the value of “X” as “-sample” in the request, variable “A” is null (which looks correct). Then I pass the value of “X” as “sample” in the request, variable “A” is assigned “sample” (still correct). But again if I change the value of “X” to “-sample”, variable “A” gets assigned “sample” (which shouldn’t happen). Dash seems to be ignored in the request. May I know what is the problem with my code here? Sorry if I’m missing something obvious. Thank you.

Update: The code seems to run fine if I restart the web app but it ignores the Dash after any request comes without a Dash.

Comment: *"only alphanumerics (ASCII characters only)"* means `a-zA-Z0-9`, not `\u0000-\u007F`. That is *all* of ASCII, not just *alphanumerics*. You can do the entire thing in a single regex: `tempParameter.matches("(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,199})?")`

Comment: Could you please paste the whole servlet code?
As that will be more helpful in debugging.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I'll try what you have suggested. 

Comment: Thanks @NajeebArif for your comment. Rohit and Andreas solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you have declared `A` ?

It seems code is correct but your variable is holding past result.

Try setting `A = null` in `else` block

Comment: Hi Rohit, Thanks for your answer. I'll try and let you know. 